# Linux+ Certification

Tags: certification

I'm currently a student in college studying computer networking. Out of all the things I'm studying, my strong suit seems to be Linux. With spring break coming up I would like to use the time to study for my Linux+ certification exam.

I'm looking for suggestions for good sites, books, etc, from those who are Linux+ certified.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I got my Linux+ a few weeks ago. Yahoo!!!
I used some of the recommended books and practice tests on www.lpi.org Thanks everyone.

Comment: you should really click the tick button next to the answer that help you to close the thread.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is the place to start, get your info, get your tests and do your certifications:
http://www.lpi.org/

Check this sites also: http://www.linuxcertified.com/

http://www.redhat.com/training/certifications/rhce/

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you start with [this tutorial by Ryan Chadwick](http://ryanstutorials.net/linuxtutorial/navigation.php)

Go step by step and try to implement it on terminal.

The best way to self-learn Linux is to get a ebook like *Linux for Dummies* and to replicate each command trying understand what they do. If this is done on a live Linux server, the results may be catastrophic, so I suggest you install free virtual machine software like Oracle VirtualBox and install any flavour of Linux in it to play around.

Answer (score 0):

I could recommend some tutorial sites and books:

[Bash_scripting_Tutorial](http://linuxconfig.org/Bash_scripting_Tutorial)

[The Linux Documentation Project](http://www.tldp.org/guides.html)

[Unix and Linux System Administration Handbook](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Unix-Linux-System-Administration-Handbook/dp/0131480057/ref=wl_it_dp_o_npd?ie=UTF8&coliid=I270OLV3FE1RFK&colid=TWC6I2KDZAT0)

Also Ubuntu has some training courses: [Ubuntu training](http://www.ubuntu.com/support/training)